# Clarity of sentences

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, commas, syntactic-analysis

I am writing an essay and I want to say a sentence:

Would it be better to say that

I initially wanted Jim to dye his hair blue , but now I see that he made the right decision.

OR

I initially wanted Jim to dye his hair blue , but now that I see him, he decided right.

Please advise

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although "You guessed right" and "You heard right" are often used (http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/right), I've never really heard the construction "He decided right" used in American English. Accordingly, I think the first sentence choice is a better one.

I think it's better for other reasons as well. For example, the second sentence is awkwardly phrased.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I appreciate it. I find it hard to decide which words I should use to make my sentence clear. For example, I write whatever I want to write in multiple forums and then decide which one to use.    
For instance, if I want to say that I want to make a cake, I would write things like  Making a cake is what I have decided I would do. 
   
b. Designing a cake is something I decided on doing.
 
   
c. I have decided to design a cake .